# Why is my generic implementation not working? (extends Comparable<? super T>>)

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I am implementing a Binary Search Tree with `BinaryNode<T>` that holds the information. In my tree class I have this line of code:

```
public class BST<T> implements BSTInterface<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

This is causing many errors such as:

```
BST.java:10: error: > expected
public class BST<T> implements BSTInterface<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
                                          ^
BST.java:10: error: <identifier> expected
public class BST<T> implements BSTInterface<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
                                                                           ^
```

I am not sure why this isn't working because that line of code works for my interface. Any help would be much appreciated! I am probably making some stupid mistake.

Answer (score 11):

I think you intended to write

```
public class BST<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements BSTInterface<T>
```

You have to put the bounds on `T` at the first mention of `T`.